# Simple BlockChain program

Tags: javascript, blockchain

I am trying to build this simple code of "BlockChain" I found it online to give me a better understanding of the blockchain technique.

But when I run it it gives me an error when it runs.

This is the error that I got:-

*import {BlockChain} from 'BlockChain';
       ^*

*SyntaxError: Unexpected token*

---

**class  Block**

```
 export class  Block{

    constructor(timestamp, data, previousHash = '') {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.data = data;
        this.previousHash = previousHash;
        // The calculation of the hash must be at the end so to ensure that all data is assigned correctly before calculation
        this.hash = this.calculateHash(); }

    calculateHash() {
        return SHA256(this.previousHash + this.timestamp + JSON.stringify(this.data)).toString();
    }
}
```

**class  BlockChain**

```
import {Block} from 'Block';



  export class  BlockChain {

    constructor() {
        this.chain = [this.createGenesisBlock()];
    }

    createGenesisBlock(){
        return new Block("2018-11-11 00:00:00", "Genesis block of simple chain", "");
    }

    getLatestBlock() {
        return this.chain[this.chain.length - 1];
    }

    addBlock(newBlock) {
        // The previous hash value of the new block is the hash value of the last block of the existing blockchain；
        newBlock.previousHash = this.getLatestBlock().hash;
        // Recalculate the hash value of the new block (because the previousHash is specified)；
        newBlock.hash = newBlock.calculateHash();
        //Add new blocks to the chain；
        this.chain.push(newBlock);
    }

    isChainValid() {
        //Traverse all the blocks
        for (let i = 1; i < this.chain.length; i++) {
            const currentBlock = this.chain[i];
            const previousBlock = this.chain[i - 1];
            //Recalculate the has value of the current block. If the hash value is not matched, it indicates that data of the block was changed without permission, and therefore the has value is not recalculated.
            if (currentBlock.hash !== currentBlock.calculateHash()) {
                console.error("hash not equal: " + JSON.stringify(currentBlock));
                return false;
            }
            // Determine whether the previousHash of the current block is equal to the hash of the previous block. If they are not equal to each other, this means that the previous block was changed without permission. Although the hash value is recalculated correctly, the hash value of the subsequent block is not recalculated, resulting the the whole chain breaking.
            if (currentBlock.previousHash !== previousBlock.calculateHash) {
                console.error("previous hash not right: " + JSON.stringify(currentBlock));
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

**Class Test**

```
import {BlockChain} from 'BlockChain';
import {Block} from 'Block';



    let simpleChain = new BlockChain();

    simpleChain.addBlock(new Block("2018-11-11 00:00:01", {amount: 10}));
    simpleChain.addBlock(new Block("2018-11-11 00:00:02", {amount: 20}));


    console.log(JSON.stringify(simpleChain, null, 4));

    console.log("is the chain valid? " + simpleChain.isChainValid());
```

Comment: How are you running the code?

Comment: It seems your import statement in Class Test failed to import the actual resource. make sure the path to import module are correct. Also check whether you installed all project dependencies. If possible share you package.json file

Comment: @stamhaney I select Test.js then run

Answer (score 2):

The code is fine. You can run the code as follows:

1. Install crypto-js using Node:

> npm install crypto-js

2. Open a Node prompt from the Command window/Terminal:

> Node

3. Open the Editor in Node:

[image]

4. Require the sha256 module. Paste the following code in the editor:

> const SHA256 = require('crypto-js/sha256');

1. Paste the Block, BlockChain and Test classes, in the editor:

**Class Block**

```
class  Block{

    constructor(timestamp, data, previousHash = '') {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.data = data;
        this.previousHash = previousHash;
        // The calculation of the hash must be at the end so to ensure that all data is assigned correctly before calculation
        this.hash = this.calculateHash(); }

    calculateHash() {
        return SHA256(this.previousHash + this.timestamp + JSON.stringify(this.data)).toString();
    }
}
```

**Class BlockChain**

```
class  BlockChain {

    constructor() {
        this.chain = [this.createGenesisBlock()];
    }

    createGenesisBlock(){
        return new Block("2018-11-11 00:00:00", "Genesis block of simple chain", "");
    }

    getLatestBlock() {
        return this.chain[this.chain.length - 1];
    }

    addBlock(newBlock) {
        // The previous hash value of the new block is the hash value of the last block of the existing blockchain；
        newBlock.previousHash = this.getLatestBlock().hash;
        // Recalculate the hash value of the new block (because the previousHash is specified)；
        newBlock.hash = newBlock.calculateHash();
        //Add new blocks to the chain；
        this.chain.push(newBlock);
    }

    isChainValid() {
        //Traverse all the blocks
        for (let i = 1; i < this.chain.length; i++) {
            const currentBlock = this.chain[i];
            const previousBlock = this.chain[i - 1];
            //Recalculate the has value of the current block. If the hash value is not matched, it indicates that data of the block was changed without permission, and therefore the has value is not recalculated.
            if (currentBlock.hash !== currentBlock.calculateHash()) {
                console.error("hash not equal: " + JSON.stringify(currentBlock));
                return false;
            }
            // Determine whether the previousHash of the current block is equal to the hash of the previous block. If they are not equal to each other, this means that the previous block was changed without permission. Although the hash value is recalculated correctly, the hash value of the subsequent block is not recalculated, resulting the the whole chain breaking.
            if (currentBlock.previousHash !== previousBlock.calculateHash) {
                console.error("previous hash not right: " + JSON.stringify(currentBlock));
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

**Class Test**

```
let simpleChain = new BlockChain();

    simpleChain.addBlock(new Block("2018-11-11 00:00:01", {amount: 10}));
    simpleChain.addBlock(new Block("2018-11-11 00:00:02", {amount: 20}));


    console.log(JSON.stringify(simpleChain, null, 4));

    console.log("is the chain valid? " + simpleChain.isChainValid());
```

5. Press ^D  to finish

This will give you the following output:

[image]